# What can I do to improve this plot to get a better idea of what the correlation is like in my data?

Tags: r, correlation, data-visualization, scatterplot

In R I've typed the following code to get my scatterplots but the plots are all very bunched up:

[image]

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2),mai=c(0.8,0.8,2,0.8));

plot(x,y,"",cex.lab=0.5,cex.axis=0.5)

plot(log(x),y,cex.lab=0.5,cex.axis=0.5,)
```

How can I modify my code to get better scatterplots?

Comment: https://www.r-bloggers.com/a-detailed-guide-to-the-ggplot-scatter-plot-in-r/ see if any of these solutions are useful. You could essentially change the colors and size of points if you have a grouping variable

Comment: Start with `plot(x,y,log="x",col="#00000010")`, thereby introducing semi-transparency to help see the overlapping symbols better.

Answer (score 3):

The `hexbin` package: my quick and painless go-to for visualizing overplotted data sets.

```
library(hexbin)

set.seed(4321)
x.axis <- c(rnorm(2000), rnorm(2000, 4, 2))
y.axis <- c(rnorm(2000), rnorm(2000, 2, 3))
point.map <- cbind(x.axis, y.axis)

# Square plot region
par(pty = "s")

# Standard R plot
plot(point.map)
```

[image]

```
# Convert coordinate data into a hexbin object
point.map.hex <- hexbin(point.map)

# Plot hexbin object with perceptually linear color ramp
plot(point.map.hex, colramp = heat.ob)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Often when there is a lot of data scatterplots simply look too bunched up like this. I would recommend another visualization, perhaps overlaid histograms or overlaid density plots.

To make the overlaid histograms you could use

```
hist(x)
hist(y, add=T)
```

and the overlaid density plots could be made using the "sm" package.

Comment: Exactly what do you propose showing histograms of and how would these *univariate* histograms reveal anything about the *bivariate* associations in a scatterplot?

Answer (score 0):

**One way to better visualize bivariate relationships is shown below. I will use `iris` data an example**

[image]

```
# install.packages("PerformanceAnalytics")
library("PerformanceAnalytics")
my_data <- iris[, c(1,3,4)] # note 1,3,4 refer to variables in your dataset
chart.Correlation(my_data, histogram=TRUE, pch=19)
```

**As depicted on the plot:**

On the lower triangle, you see bivariate plots with a smoothing line.

On the upper triangle, you can see the actual correlations and the extent to which they are statistically significant (* *p<.05*; ** *p<.01*; *** *p<.001* *)

You do not necessarily need histograms, so you could set 
`histogram=FALSE` if you like

Comment: Could you show us how this addresses the question about the *single* relationship exhibited in the scatterplot and how to improve scatterplots?

Comment: @whuber thank you. I tried to change the answer so it helps to depict scatterplots better

Comment: This solution is identical to the original scatterplot when there are two variables--the bivariate situation of the question.  As such, it doesn't seem to be any advance on what is already in the question.